# How to plot multiple ggplot_gtable objects on multiple pages of a pdf?

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2, gtable

This is not a repetitive question though the title might seem similar.

Let's say I have a function f1() which plots an object of class "gTable,grob,gDesc" once. I'm using grid.draw() to plot the object.

So when we call :

```
pdf("filename.pdf", height = 10, weight =12)
f1()
dev.off()
```

This will give one page of pdf which is what i wanted.

However when i want two plots in a single pdf by the code :

```
pdf("filename.pdf")
f1()
f1()
dev.off()
```

I get is a single page pdf with just the second plot.That is the first plot was overwritten by the second. To overcome this I am using grid.newpage() but that adds one extra blank page in the pdf. How to avoid this? I can use an extra argument to create a newpage only if the argument is set. However do we have any other option?

I have played with grid.arrange() and also the onefile argument in pdf() but nothing worked.

Also when I try to plot these on the R plot window then it overwrites on the existing open graphical device. So after plotting second time, i am unable to view the first plot by using the back arrow.
[back arrow of R plot window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atMDi.png)

Edit : sample R code which plots an object of class "gTable, grob, gDesc"

```
xxx <- function(){
set.seed(1111)
dd <- diamonds[sample(1:nrow(diamonds), 1000, replace = TRUE), ]
dd$color <- sample(letters[1:2], 1000, replace = TRUE)

p  <- ggplot(data = dd, aes(x = cut))  
p1 <- p + geom_bar(fill = "orange", alpha = 1) + facet_wrap(~color)+
          ggtitle("Main title")+scale_y_continuous("frequency", expand = c(0, 0))+
          labs(x = "cut", y = "frequency")+
          theme(panel.background = element_rect(colour = "white"),
                axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
                panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
               legend.position = "bottom") 

  p2 <- p + geom_line(aes(y = price), alpha = 0)+
            labs(x = "", y = "price")+expand_limits(y = 0) +
            stat_summary(aes(y = price, group = 1, colour = "mean"), fun.y = "mean", geom = c("point"))+ 
            stat_summary(aes(y = price, group = 1, colour = "mean"), fun.y = "mean", geom = c("line"))+ 
            stat_summary(aes(y = price, group = 1, colour = "median"), fun.y = "median", geom = "point")+
            stat_summary(aes(y = price, group = 1, colour = "median"), fun.y = "median", geom = "line")+
            scale_colour_manual(name = "" ,breaks = c("mean", "median"), values = c("red", "blue"))+
            facet_wrap(~color)+ylab("Exposures")+
            theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = "white"),
                  panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                  panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                  panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = "grey50"),
                  legend.position = "bottom") 

  xx <- ggplot_build(p1)
  yy <- ggplot_build(p2)

  nrow <- length(unique(xx$panel$layout$ROW))
  ncol <- length(unique(xx$panel$layout$COL))
  npanel <- length(xx$panel$layout$PANEL)

  g1 <- ggplot_gtable(xx)
  g2 <- ggplot_gtable(yy)

  pp <- c(subset(g1$layout, grepl("panel", g1$layout$name), se = t:r))
  g <- gtable_add_grob(g1, g2$grobs[grepl("panel", g1$layout$name)], 
                       pp$t, pp$l, pp$b, pp$l)

  func1 <- function(grob){
        widths <- grob$widths
        grob$widths[1] <- widths[3]
        grob$widths[3] <- widths[1]
        grob$vp[[1]]$layout$widths[1] <- widths[3]
        grob$vp[[1]]$layout$widths[3] <- widths[1]

        grob$children[[1]]$hjust <- 1 - grob$children[[1]]$hjust 
        grob$children[[1]]$vjust <- 1 - grob$children[[1]]$vjust 
        grob$children[[1]]$x <- unit(1, "npc") - grob$children[[1]]$x
        grob
     }


  index <- which(g2$layout$name == "ylab") 
  ylab <- g2$grobs[[index]]                # Extract that grob
  ylab <- func1(ylab) 
  ylab$children[[1]]$rot <- ylab$children[[1]]$rot + 180
  g <- gtable_add_cols(g, g2$widths[g2$layout[index, ]$l], pos = max(pp$r))
  g <-gtable_add_grob(g,ylab, t = min(pp$t), l = max(pp$r)+1, 
                      b = max(pp$b), r = max(pp$r)+1,
                      clip = "off", name = "2ndylab")

  j = 1
  k = 0

  for(i in 1:npanel){ 
    if ((i %% ncol == 0) || (i == npanel)){
      k = k + 1
      # swap the 2nd y-axis label

     index <- which(g2$layout$name == "axis_l-1")  # Which grob
     yaxis <- g2$grobs[[index]]                    # Extract the grob
     ticks <- yaxis$children[[2]]
      ticks$widths <- rev(ticks$widths)
     ticks$grobs <- rev(ticks$grobs)
     ticks$grobs[[1]]$x <- ticks$grobs[[1]]$x - unit(1, "npc")
     ticks$grobs[[2]] <- func1(ticks$grobs[[2]])
     yaxis$children[[2]] <- ticks
     if ((k == 1) || ((i == npanel) & (i%%ncol != 0)))#to ensure just once d secondary axisis printed 
      g <- gtable_add_cols(g,g2$widths[g2$layout[index,]$l], max(pp$r[j:i]))
      g <- gtable_add_grob(g,yaxis,max(pp$t[j:i]),max(pp$r[j:i])+1, max(pp$b[j:i])
                       , max(pp$r[j:i]) + 1, clip = "off", name = "2ndaxis")
     j = i + 1
  }
}

 pp <- c(subset(g2$layout, name == "guide-box", se = t:r))
 g <- gtable_add_grob(g, g2$grobs[[which(g2$layout$name == "guide-box")]], t = pp$t, 
                   l = pp$r, b = pp$b, r = pp$r )
 grid.draw(g)
}
```

This is a sample function. So if I call the following code:

```
pdf("zzz.pdf")
xxx()
xxx()
dev.off()
```

Only a single page pdf is created in above case. And if you simply call

```
xxx()
xxx()
```

Then in the R plot window Ican just view the second plot. The back arrow button is disabled since the first plot was overwritten.

Comment: `grid.arrange` from the `gridExtra` package

Comment: `grid.newpage()` is the right approach

Comment: Can you try using `apply` od `lapply`? E.g. `lapply(data, f1)`. And provide a small reproducible example.

Comment: @baptiste, yes , i did read in other threads too but then how to get rid of the blank page in the pdf without using an argument? and also how to overcome the difficulty being faced with R plot window?

Comment: I can't help you without a reproducible example

Comment: @baptiste  I have added an example. Please do help with your suggestions

Comment: please make it a *minimal* example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use `grid.newpage()` after the first plot,

```
 xxx <- function() {gg <- ggplotGrob(ggplot()); grid.draw(gg)}

 pdf("zzz.pdf")
 xxx()
 grid.newpage()
 xxx()
 dev.off()
```

[image]

You may find it easier to have the function return a grob rather than drawing it, and define a print/draw method for a list of such objects to be displayed. See `gridExtra:::print.arrangelist` for such a strategy,

```
xxx <- function() {gg <- ggplotGrob(ggplot()); gg}

plots <- marrangeGrob(replicate(3, xxx(), simplify = FALSE), nrow=1, ncol=1)
pdf("zzz.pdf")
print(plots)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for this. I'm aware of this one.  This will solve my first query but would to know how to solve the second issue. If we compare the   Base R plot() function, we can access the previous plots on R plot window using the beck arrow button. However whle working with this object it overwrites on each other.

Comment: the interactive behaviour is probably device-dependent (or IDE)